# 301 htaccess dir redirect to a different subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I would redirect the whole dir "https://sub.domain.ext/dir1" to another location on a different machine "https://sub1.domain.ext/dir1", I'm using in /.htaccess the following rule with no success:
The page simply doesnt't redirect.

```
Rewriterule ^dir1/(.*) https://sub1.domain.ext/dir1/$1 [R=301,L]

# this is the whole ht access
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Morfeus
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [F]
</IfModule>
# supress php errors     
php_value display_errors off

# force https 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://sub.domain.ext/$1 [R,L]
```

any tips?

Scenario: ubuntu+apache

others htaccess rules worsk fine

thx

Comment: What is not working? Can you complete .htaccess?

Comment: The page doesn't redirect

Comment: Where is this .htaccess located? Inside `/dir1/` or a level above it? Is there a .htaccess in`/dir1/` also?

Comment: htaccess is located in the root dir  one step above dir1/
in dir1 I have an htaccess: php_value display_errors 0

Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^(\d+)*$ ./shorturl.php?FB_pageid=$1

Comment: I asked 2 questions actually

Comment: OK, I delete the second htacces and now runs.
thx

Comment: Yes deleting that will make it work but what about this rule of `shorturl.php`?

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the htaccess file in the dir1/, the problem was solved.